# How to make a div have 2 rows max lines and get ellipsis?

Tags: html, css

**CODE:**

```
    <div class="center-block" style="width: 250px;">
        <div style="height: 250px; /* 1:1 ratio */ overflow: hidden; background-color: #f8ff15;">
        </div>
        <div class="text-center" id="max2lines-div" style="background-color: lightyellow; width: 100%; max-height:2.2em;">
            <p id="subject-text" style=" text-overflow: ellipsis;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt rem odit quis quaerat. In dolorem praesentium velit ea esse consequuntur cum fugit sequi voluptas ut possimus voluptatibus deserunt nisi eveniet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem voluptates vel dolorum autem ex repudiandae iste quasi. Minima explicabo qui necessitatibus porro nihil aliquid deleniti ullam repudiandae dolores corrupti eaque</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g2anpehk/5/

Code is to present 250 * 250 picture and picture's subject. (`#subject-text`)

But subject text is too much and overflow the max-height of `#max2lines-div` and `text-overflow: ellipsis`is useless.

**Question:**

What I want to make is that only showing 2 lines maximum with `text-overflow: ellipsis;`. So subject should be ended with `...`

How can I fix it?

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make use of **[line-clamp](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/)** with browsers prefixes...However it will work only on `-webkit` engine browsers...

As mozila use **[gecko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_(software))** engine, so it will not work on it...So for the hack you can use `max-height`

```css
#subject-text {
  max-height: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  line-height: normal;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-line-clamp: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-block" style="width: 250px;">
  <div style="height: 250px; /* 1:1 ratio */ overflow: hidden; background-color: #f8ff15;">
  </div>
  <div class="text-center" id="max2lines-div" style="background-color: lightyellow; width: 100%; max-height:2.2em;">
    <p id="subject-text" style=" text-overflow: ellipsis;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt rem odit quis quaerat. In dolorem praesentium velit ea esse consequuntur cum fugit sequi voluptas ut possimus voluptatibus deserunt nisi eveniet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Dolorem voluptates vel dolorum autem ex repudiandae iste quasi. Minima explicabo qui necessitatibus porro nihil aliquid deleniti ullam repudiandae dolores corrupti eaque</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

line-clamp is your answer, but its not well supported.

try this :

```
#max2lines-div p {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}
```

and check : https://caniuse.com/#search=line-clamp

Comment: While this code might provide an answer to the question, an explanation of how it solves the issue is recommended. Please update the answer with some explanation of how and why this code solves the issue.